# Cannot open popup in Excel Web Addin VS2019

Tags: azure-active-directory, office-js, msal.js

I am working on an Excel Addin project using asp.net core 3.1. I want to open a popup to enable users to log in to the system using Azure Ad authentication. I use window.open("url") but this always returns null regardless of the fact that I already disable the popup blocker in IE.
I am using Excel 365, Window 10 enterprise version 1809, Internet Explorer version 11.1577.17763.0.
Note that I cannot user Dialog API for office because the Msal library for Azure Ad authentication uses window.open behind the scene.
Can anyone provide me some hints on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MSAL and the Office dialog API. See this sample: [Office-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/master/Samples/auth/Office-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET), especially the file [Add-in-Home-Index.js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/blob/65dc7765e8b24208dca69927a7b211a2bc19a178/Samples/auth/Outlook-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET/Outlook-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNETWeb/Scripts/Add-in-Home-Index.js).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference. This sample is for asp.net framework. I am not sure if it is possible without much of effort to adapt it to work with asp.net core. But it looks promising. I will look into that.

Comment: Hi Rick, I have looked into the code and as far as I can see, the samplr you mentioned performs authentication for the web application, not the Excel user. So it does not act on behalf of the signed in user. Is that so?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "on behalf of the signed in user". It gets the names of 3 files on the signed in user's OneDrive account.

Comment: Hi Rick, 
The authentication seems ok actually. I have overlooked it. But one thing still confuses me. The access token is cached and re-used in each api call. There is no treatment when the access token is expired. Do you know any resources that discuss this issue?

Comment: Search for `msal expired and "refresh token"`